# Is ftp connections and actions are logged in REDHAT 7?

Tags: linux, vpn, ftp, logging, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using a REDHAT 7 server through a VPN connection (with some other users). I want to know if FTP connections and operations are logged somewhere. I tried to look around /var/log but nothing seemed clear to me.

Comment: Have you asked whoever configured the server this question?

Answer (score 0):

If there are ftp connections, you must have an ftp server (daemon, ftpd).  You should check its configuration: has logging been enabled, and whereto?